# How many times K-means Spark Streaming processed the same data?

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, k-means, spark-streaming

I'm a newbie with **Spark Streaming** and I want to use **K-means**, but when I study this I can't understand how many times K-means on Spark Streaming use the same data?

That is to say, the K-means algorithm is iterative, so how can I control the number of times that it runs on the same data?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means essentially is about having `k` cluster centroids. In every iteration you update the cluster to which data points belong and then recompute the k centroids. So right off the bat, the ***best*** way to stop the k-means run is not by *how many times have you run the algorithm* but by whether the centroid computed in this run is the same as the previous one.

When the points will stabilize in the clusters, the centroids will stabilize too and this means that any further iteration would not change the clusters and that is where you should stop.

But, you can, if you wish to, stop earlier too. You can program the algo to run a max number of iterations. Since k-means runs over and over, it has some kind of loop (while, for, foreach..). You can put a loop counter in there and stop when you have had the desired runs. Alternatively you can stop when the change in previous cluster centroids and the new cluster centroids is below a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! 
I understand the traditional K-means, but my question is about **K-means in Spark Streaming**, where the input is a **stream**. I think algorithm take a "window" of data and apply K-means in those data. But my big question is how many interations execute in each window. 
I hope I was clear. Thank you again!

Comment: @majitux: If the stream is not many times the size of your RAM, read it all (in an array maybe) and perform K-means. Otherwise, you are only going to lose your stream.

Comment: @majitux: For the number of iterations, read the second and third para of my answer. I've explained the same thing there. How exactly to stop your algo can be answered only after taking a look at your code.

Comment: OK, I understand you but is it possible to determine in advance the number of iterations in each window? Thanks!

Comment: @majitux: Without knowing the data in advance, we cannot predict how many cycles it will take to stabilize the centroids. However you can decide for yourself how many iterations you are capable of and then run only those many times. Bad idea though given the nature of K-means

Comment: It's me again! I was thinking, Can I put a counter for to know the number of iterations in each data's window? This is because I need compare to another algorithm, but I need to know that number. 
Thank you again!

Comment: @majitux: Of course you can. I can't tell how without looking at the code. But it shouldn't be difficult for you to do too. Keep a counter and update it whenever you iterate. Print it in the end and you'll know.